# Solidity: Pass multiple return values as argument to function?

Tags: solidity

Why does the following not work:

```
pragma solidity ^0.4.24;

contract Test {

    struct S {
        string s;
        uint u;
    }

    function returnTwoValues() private returns (string s, uint u) {
        s = "123";
        u = 123;
    }

    constructor() {
        S memory s = S(returnTwoValues());
    }
}
```

I'm getting a

```
TypeError: Wrong argument count for struct constructor: 1 arguments given but expected 2.
```

Do I really need to store the return values in temporary variables?

Comment: If you're expecting to get a `struct S` from function `returnTwoValues`, then this function needs to return `struct S`. Otherwise, ylou should write `(string s, uint u) = returnTwoValues()`.

Comment: That's unfortunately not yet possible accross contract boundaries. I wonder mainly why, if a function returns multiple values, I can't pass them directly to a function that takes these exact values as arguments (I'm calling here the struct's constructor, which takes two arguments).

Answer (score 3):

This works altough the entire contract is a bit weird. 
Why would you want to set a memory variable in the constructor? 
Constructor is used to initiate state variables.

```
pragma solidity ^0.4.24;

contract Test {

    struct S {
        string s;
        uint u;
    }

    function returnTwoValues() private returns (string s, uint u) {
        s = "123";
        u = 123;
        return(s, u);
    }

    constructor() {
        (string memory a, uint b) = returnTwoValues();
        S memory s = S(a,b);
    }
}
```

Comment: My question is why I can't do it without the temporary variables you suggest.

Comment: Because returnTwoValues() actually returns a tuple that consists out of (string s, uint u). 
A tuple would be 1 argument , therefore we need to 'deconstruct' the tuple. 
Previously you could have done var (a, b) = returnTwoValues(); but that's deprecated.

Comment: that should be an answer. Is 'Tuple' a type in solidity? can a function be written to take a tuple as argument? how so?

Comment: Structs are considered tuples and can be arguments and return values for internal or external-to-contract calls.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
pragma solidity ^0.4.24;

contract Test {

    struct S {
        string s;
        uint u;
    }

    function returnOneValue() private pure returns (S s) {
        s.s = "123";
        s.u = 123;
    }

    constructor() {
        S memory s = returnOneValue();
    }
}
```

Or this:

```
pragma solidity ^0.4.24;

contract Test {

    struct S {
        string s;
        uint u;
    }

    function returnTwoValues() private pure returns (string s, uint u) {
        s = "123";
        u = 123;
    }

    constructor() public {
        (string memory _s, uint _u) = returnTwoValues();
        S memory s = S(_s, _u);
    }
}
```

Comment: That's not what I want - such a function can't be called from an external contract and the second uses the temporary variables, which I wonder if can be avoided

Comment: @user1282931: You cannot return a struct outside of the contract (at present).

Comment: I know - that's not what I asked for.